# mongodb update nested array from a array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a array in mongodb document.

```
 {
  _id: 1,
  jobs:[
   {
     _id:1,
     time: "08:00",
     status: "pending",
     user: 'user1'
   },
   {
     _id:2,
     time: "09:00",
     status: "pending",
     user: 'user1'
   },
   {
     _id:3,
     time: "07:30",
     status: "done",
     user: 'user2'
   }
]
}
```

now I have a updated jobs array like this.

```
jobs:[
   {
     _id:1,
     time: "10:00",
     status: "done"
   },
   {
     _id:2,
     time: "11:00",
     status: "done"
   }
]
```

updated document should like this

```
{
  _id: 1,
  jobs:[
   {
     _id:1,
     time: "10:00", // updated
     status: "done" // updated
     user: 'user1'
   },
   {
     _id:2,
     time: "11:00", // updated
     status: "done", // updated
     user: "user1"
   },
   {
     _id:3,
     time: "07:30",
     status: "done",
     user: 'user2'
   }
]
}
```

I tried using update and $set and no luck so far

how do I update the only the values in the updated array in to the mongodb document? thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected result? A document with _id:1, in which jobs with _id:1, _id:2 are updated and job with _id:3 stayed the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using an update with a pipeline:

1. Add the new data into the document as `newData`
2. Using a `$map` to loop over the `jobs` items, for each item merge it with the matching item in `newData`.

**EDIT** (consider partial match):

```
db.collection.update(
  {_id: 1},
  [{$addFields: {
    newData: [
        {_id: 1, time: "10:00", status: "done"},
        {_id: 2, time: "11:00", status: "done"}
      ]
    }
  },
  {$project: {
    jobs: {$map: {
      input: "$jobs",
      in: {$mergeObjects: [
         "$$this",
         {$cond: [
           {$gte: [{$indexOfArray: ["$newData._id", "$$this._id"]}, 0]},
           {$arrayElemAt: ["$newData", {$indexOfArray: ["$newData._id", "$$this._id"]}]},
           ]}
         ]}
       ]}
    }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/olFZk7PylP0)

Comment: that's amazing. thanks. I was thinking about this all day

Comment: how do I use this with mongoose updateOne?

Comment: The same. Just replace update with updateOne

Comment: it doesn't work!. it just replaced all the elements in the array. sorry

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer

Comment: bro. how did you learn this? it took me 3 hours to find this error

Comment: I just don't like to be wrong. When I'm wrong I'm working extra fast to be right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247951/discussion-between-lahiru-supun-and-nimrod-serok).